# VPN Connection on VPS, No Remote Desktop

Tags: vpn, vps, remote-desktop, remote-access, windows-server-2016

I have a VPS running on WS 2016 (not ADC) and I used to connect via Remote Desktop Interface. Now I installed Remote Access for VPN, but when Routing and Remote Access Feature is on, I cannot connect the server via Remote Desktop. The server also does not give permisson to enable Direct Access, throwing error about TrustedHosts. And I connected VPN via client machine but I had no internet access.

Appreciate for help.

Comment: When you are connected to the VPN, are you trying to RDP using the 'internal' IP of the server?

Comment: No, I am trying to connect server's external IP, as usual. How can I connect with internal?